# Help finding headset

Tags: headset, restoration

I have only been able to find a headset that measures 1-5/16" on the small end of the bearing cup that goes into the headtube on the bike. All of the bearing cups I've found are 1-3/4" on the large end and take a large diameter bearing. The headset bearing cups I have 1-5/16" bearing cup o.d. but the large end measures 1-5/8". Where do I find a headset like that?

Comment: What bike are you looking to replace the headset on? Are you positive you are measuring correctly?

Comment: This question may be similar and has details about how to measure properly.http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/which-threaded-headset-size-do-i-use

Answer (score 1):

Cane creek has a headset finder  table on their website. You can search by dimension or bike brand and model.